# Generalisation of the Harnack enequality

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

Let $G \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ a domain and K a compact subset of G.
Show the existence of $M>1$ such that:
$\frac{1}{M} \leq \frac{h(z)}{h(w)} \leq M $ for all $z,w \in
 K$ and all positive harmonic functions $h: G \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
First I don't see how this inequality refers to the Harnack inequality. I got the hint to think about under which conditions of G and K the inequality is the "classic Harnack inequality". 
Futhermore I should use an argument about covering which I don't know what it is.